# Colcon build fail, rclpy

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to Colcon build ROS2 Rolling (https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html), I've faced this error:

colcon build --symlink-install

> Starting >>> rclpy
> --- stderr: rclpy
>
> CMake Error at
> /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146
> (message):   Could NOT find Python3
> (missing: Python3_LIBRARIES
> Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS   Development)
> (found version "3.9.10") Call Stack
> (most recent call first):
> /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393
> (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
> /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2214
> (find_package_handle_standard_args)
> /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython3.cmake:300
> (include)   CMakeLists.txt:40
> (find_package)
>
> --- Failed   <<< rclpy [5.33s, exited with code 1]

My system Python is 3.8.10, my system Ubuntu 20.04. From the logs, it looks like 3.8 is not being found, while 3.9 is picked instead (3.9 is installed too on my system). The other 300s or so packages of ROS2 Rolling installed without issues.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397953/colcon-build-fail,-rclpy/) by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on 2022-07-20**:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71606313/colcon-build-fail-rclpy/73048567#73048567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the error was due to colcon picking up the anaconda python, instead of the default OS python (3.8.10 in my case).

> Sometimes rclpy fails to be imported
> because the expected C extension
> libraries are not found. If so,
> compare the libraries present in the
> directory with the one mentioned in
> the error message. Assuming a file
> with a similar name exists (same
> prefix like _rclpy. and same suffix
> like .so but a different Python
> version / architecture) you are using
> a different Python interpreter than
> which was used to build the C
> extension. Be sure to use the same
> Python interpreter as the one used to
> build the binary.

https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#import-failing-without-library-present-on-the-system

---

Originally posted by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) with karma: 50 on 2022-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2022-07-21**:
Hi, did rebuilding the workspace as indicated in the link fix the problem? If not and you fixed the issue, could you edit the answer explaining how you did it? Many thanks!

**Comment by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on 2022-07-21**:
Not tested sorry, I've settled for installing galactic from apt-get.